# How do you read 麻色?

Tags: kanji, readings, colors

Don't know if it should be read as まいろ, まあいろ, あさいろ or in some other way. Couldn't find it in any dictionary.

Context: [image: screenshot]

Comment: Out of interest, what game is that? (I'm fond of old games.)

Comment: It's 雫 by Leaf, original PC-98 edition.

Comment: It's just a trivia but 雫 was written by 高橋龍也 in 1996. His latest work in 2015 is アイドルマスター シンデレラガールズ.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's read like a regular compound word, あさいろ

[Here's a passage](http://www.aozora.gr.jp/cards/000879/files/52_15239.html) from Aozora Bunko with furigana:

```
何か妙な[粉]{こな}をふりかけた[麻色]{あさいろ}の[縮]{ちぢ}れ毛の[鬘]{かずら}である。
```

Answer (score 8):

- 灰 (はい)

  灰色 (はいいろ)
- 茶 (ちゃ)

  茶色 (ちゃいろ)
- 黄 (き)

  黄色 (きいろ)
- 銀 (ぎん)

  銀色 (ぎんいろ)

I'm not 100% sure, but the trend seems to be attaching いろ directly to the standalone word. Going from this, I would assume that 麻色 is read as あさいろ.

Apologies for not being able to provide a confident answer.